# Inserting one table's complete column data to a particular column in another table in Microsoft SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server, insert

I m having two tables `COMPONENTS(sno,comp_name,quantity,costperunit,totalcost)` and `COST(sno,comp_name,costperunit)`.. in Microsfot SQL Server

I m prompting user to enter `costperunit` value and updating immediately in `COST` table.
I want to import all the values of `costperunit` column to `COMPONENTS` from `COST` Table.

I have tried this :

```
insert into COMPONENTS(costperunit) 
    select costperunit from COST where COST.sno=COMPONENTS.sno
```

but I m unable to achieve the required functionality.

Somebody please suggest me better query to do this..
Thanks in Advance..

Comment: Are there any errors?

Comment: Yes.. It was showing that "cannot bound compoenets.sno "

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update (!) all values, why are you trying to insert ? Try to use "update from select" way:

```
UPDATE components
SET components.costperunit=cost.costperunit
FROM cost
INNER JOIN components ON cost.sno=components.sno
```

Even better to add WHERE clause to update only changed values: